# Bash: grep including newline

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Trying to regex everything between two braces `{` `}`.  Similar problem to
[Regex to match any character including newline - Vi & Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13603/regex-to-match-any-character-including-newline), but I don't understand the solution provided.

---

Using:

```
nft list table inet filter
```

Returns this:

```
table inet filter {
    set ipaddr {
        type ipv4_addr
        flags timeout
        elements = { 192.168.1.102, 192.168.1.119,
                 192.168.1.133, 192.168.1.134 }
    }
}
```

I would like to use regex to get everything inside the elements such as:

```
192.168.1.102,192.168.1.119,192.168.1.133,192.168.1.134
```

I thought I could use `grep`, but whatever works will be great.

Answer (score 1):

The information in the link is specific to vi/vim regex and is not directly applicable to grep.

Probably the equivalent in grep is to use perl compatible regular expressions (PCRE), with the `s` modifier that tells the regex engine to include newline in the `.` "any character" set (normally, `.` means any character *except* newline).

So for example with `pcregrep` using the `M`ultiline flag:

```
$ pcregrep -Mo '(?s)elements = {.*?}' yourexample
elements = { 192.168.1.102, 192.168.1.119,
                 192.168.1.133, 192.168.1.134 }
```

You can force something similar in regular GNU grep by using the `-z` flag as a proxy for `-M`:

```
grep -zPo '(?s)elements = {.*?}'
```

If you want to format the matched text as well, I'd switch to perl proper ex.

```
$ perl -00nE 'say $1 =~ s/\n\s*/ /r if m/elements = {(.*?)}/s' yourdata
 192.168.1.102, 192.168.1.119, 192.168.1.133, 192.168.1.134
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be:

```
nft list table inet filter | sed -zne 's/^.*elements = { //; s/ }.*$//; s/[ \n]\+/ /gp'
```

Here, we are using:

- the `-z` option to treat the whole input as a single line.
- the `-n` option to suppress automatic printing of pattern space.

In the script part:

- The first script (`s/^.*elements = { //;`) deletes the first part starting from beginning and going until `elements = {`  string on input.
- The second script (`s/ }.*$//;`) deletes the rest starting from  `}` until the end of input.
- The third script (`s/[ \n]\+/ /gp`) replaces any multiple white space (new-line and space characters) with a single space character `g`lobally and `p`rints the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `sed` solution (thanks @FedonKadifeli for the suggestion on shortening my initial command):

```
nft list table inet filter | sed -zn 's/.*elements = { \([0-9,\. \n]*\) }.*/\1/; s/\n//; s/  \+/ /p'
```

We pipe the output of `nft list table inet filter` to a series of `sed` commands:

- `s/.*elements = { \([0-9,\. \n]*\) }.*/\1/` selects anything between the `elements` brackets.
- `s/\n//` removes any newlines in the selection.
- `s/  \+/ /p` replaces multiple space with a single space.

From [`man sed`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/sed.1.html):

```
-n, --quiet, --silent

          suppress automatic printing of pattern space

-z, --null-data

          separate lines by NUL characters
```

The output is:

```
192.168.1.102, 192.168.1.119, 192.168.1.133, 192.168.1.134
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bash regex statement.

```bsh
$ [[ $(nft list table inet filter) =~ \
  elements[\ =]+\{([^}]*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]//[[:space:]]/}"
```